# Elastic search not giving results

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been using ES for a while, but today is not working. I recreated my the docker-compose (can be smt there?), these are the data i've in ES:

edit: this is my input (here i've `_source = False`)

```
{'mappings': {'doc': {'_all': {'enabled': False}, 'dynamic': False, 'properties': {u'string': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'}, '_time': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'date'}, u'float': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'float'}, u'datetime': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'date'}, u'boolean': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'boolean'}, u'integer': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'long'}}, '_source': {'enabled': False}}}}
```

Schema:

```
{
  "07533744-b0e6-4a2f-8e94-1f7501589fee": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "properties": {
          "_time": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "boolean": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "datetime": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "float": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "integer": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "string": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1465555846775",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "-nZGMXbFRryraL0gPnr80g",
        "version": {
          "created": "2030399"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

Documents (some) with `match_all` query:

```
{
  "took": 15,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "07533744-b0e6-4a2f-8e94-1f7501589fee",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "49279857-84a7-4570-ad8e-9051079ca0ac",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "string": "1",
            "_time": "2016-06-10T12:50:59.509593",
            "float": 1.1,
            "datetime": "2016-06-10T12:50:59.497620",
            "boolean": false,
            "integer": 1
          }
        }
      },
```

now the query:
`{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match": {"integer": 1}}]}}}`

returns

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

any idea where the problem can be?

Edit:
querying with curl
`curl -XGET -d '{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match": {"integer": 1}}]}}}' http://192.168.99.100:9200/07533744-b0e6-4a2f-8e94-1f7501589fee/doc/_search` (no results)

`curl -XGET -d '{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match": {"_id": "49279857-84a7-4570-ad8e-9051079ca0ac"}}]}}}' http://192.168.99.100:9200/07533744-b0e6-4a2f-8e94-1f7501589fee/doc/_search` (gets a result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `term` query instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "integer": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Note that your document doesn't comply to the mapping you're showing us.

```
    "_source": {
      "doc": {
        "string": "1",
        "_time": "2016-06-10T12:50:59.509593",
        "float": 1.1,
        "datetime": "2016-06-10T12:50:59.497620",
        "boolean": false,
        "integer": 1
      }
    }
```

should be like this, i.e. without the `doc` field.

```
    "_source": {
        "string": "1",
        "_time": "2016-06-10T12:50:59.509593",
        "float": 1.1,
        "datetime": "2016-06-10T12:50:59.497620",
        "boolean": false,
        "integer": 1

    }
```

Comment: same result. it was working before with match. it can be a bug or a problem of the elasticsearch image. or my pc. the rest is correct?

Comment: Weird, how do you run your query?

Comment: Can you update your question with the query you'd do via curl?

Comment: i put the curl queries. i can actually recreate the whole thing

Comment: Your document is wrong compared to the mapping you have. You shouldn't have all your fields in the `doc` object otherwise the mapping won't apply. All your fields should be immediate children of the `_source``

Comment: the fact is that i use this call `es.index(index=schema_id, id=id, doc_type='doc', body=es_body)` where `schema_id = 2bef7812-2ee1-4cc0-b9ff-c9e952589a08` `id=72def658-eddd-49be-a0d6-e5ee95121feb` and es_body = `{"string": "9", "_time": "2016-06-10T13:58:27.990517", "float": 9.9, "datetime": "2016-06-10T13:58:28.039572", "boolean": false, "integer": 9}` so i don't get why it's adding the doc in the wrong format.

Comment: Maybe that's an older document from when you were testing earlier?

Comment: mmm, i recreated. i've to test the code. I see that there's a `doc` more. but i cant figure out where it's created.

Comment: i found the deal, i was using the bulk (i had a flag set to have it async) function in a wrong way

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out! Should be working after that, whether with `match` or `term`

Answer (score 1):

Try the same query you want, but make a little change

```
GET 07533744-b0e6-4a2f-8e94-1f7501589fee/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "doc.integer": 1
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Use **doc.integer** instead of **integer**

Comment: @EsseTi i have inserted the same mapping and document given above it is working fine for me.. Earlier which you were trying was not even working for me but this is

Comment: @EsseTi are you using sense plugin or curl request to query elasticsearch..?